# Sorting Dictionary of Strings into an Dictionary

Tags: sorting, dictionary, swift2

I'm trying to sort an Dictionary that contains a lot of Dictionaries inside using Swift 2.

```
var dicListItems: [String: [String: AnyObject]] = [
    "Micke": ["LastName": "Andrius", "Age": 41],
    "Brian": ["LastName": "Zini", "Age": 35],
    "Frank": ["LastName": "Kramer", "Age": 28],
    "Derek": ["LastName": "Allen", "Age": 25]
]
```

I'd like to sort by some different ways:

1) From LastName:

```
[
    "Derek": ["LastName": "Allen", "Age": 25],
    "Micke": ["LastName": "Andrius", "Age": 41],
    "Frank": ["LastName": "Kramer", "Age": 28],
    "Brian": ["LastName": "Zini", "Age": 35]
]
```

2) From FirstName:

```
[
    "Brian": ["LastName": "Zini", "Age": 35],
    "Derek": ["LastName": "Allen", "Age": 25],
    "Frank": ["LastName": "Kramer", "Age": 28],
    "Micke": ["LastName": "Andrius", "Age": 41]
]
```

3) From Age:

```
[
    "Derek": ["LastName": "Allen", "Age": 25],
    "Brian": ["LastName": "Zini", "Age": 35],
    "Frank": ["LastName": "Kramer", "Age": 28],
    "Micke": ["LastName": "Andrius", "Age": 41]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your situation:

- Dictionary (and Set) is unordered collection (not like Array https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105).
- Where is your "FirstName"  in your demo data?

I suppose that you can convert your data into this kind of things (it's an Array so sortable):

```
var dicListItems: [[String : AnyObject]] = [
["FirstName" :"Micke", "LastName": "Andrius", "Age": 41],
["FirstName" : "Brian", "LastName": "Zini", "Age": 35],
["FirstName" : "Frank", "LastName": "Kramer", "Age": 28],
["FirstName" : "Derek", "LastName": "Allen", "Age": 25]
]
```

Then you can use .sort function of swift to sort your Array. For example, this is a sort by FirstName:

```
let dictListItems: [[String : AnyObject]] = [["FirstName" :"Micke", "LastName": "Andrius", "Age": 41],     ["FirstName" : "Brian", "LastName": "Zini", "Age": 35], ["FirstName" : "Frank", "LastName": "Kramer", "Age": 28], ["FirstName" : "Derek", "LastName": "Allen", "Age": 25]]

let sortedList = dictListItems.sort {
        item1, item2 in
        let firstName1 = item1["FirstName"] as! String
        let firstName2 = item2["FirstName"] as! String
        return firstName1.compare(firstName2) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
```

Comment: The model that I have is that that I sent, but the kind of data is different (I just modified to send here an example). Is it possible to sort in that way? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem, it is Objective-C, not Swift.
Second: you can't sort a Dictionary, you should use Array instead.
The solution in Swift 2 is here:

```js
var listItems = [
    ["FirstName": "Micke", "LastName": "Andrius", "Age": 41],
    ["FirstName": "Brian", "LastName": "Zini", "Age": 35],
    ["FirstName": "Frank", "LastName": "Kramer", "Age": 28],
    ["FirstName": "Derek", "LastName": "Allen", "Age": 25]
]
listItems.sortInPlace( { ($0["FirstName"] as! String) < ($1["FirstName"] as! String)} )
print(listItems)
```

Obviously you can change the key in the sorting condition.